# Is it safe to hardcode internal storage path in android?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing an Android App using flutter, which downloads some images from internet and stores them in a directory inside internal storage (the directory and it's content should be visible to user).

I tried `path_provider` package but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
print(directory);
```

Terminal Output (tested on real Android device without SD Card):

```
W/ContextImpl( 6856): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.test.test/files
I/flutter ( 6856): Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test.test/files'
```

I want the root directory of internal storage but it returns app's specific local directory. So I decided to hardcode `/storage/emulated/0/` as root directory.

Is this solution safe?

If not, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: We dont believe that it returns an app specific directory. And why are there two such directories printed ? getExternalStorageDirectory() gives /storage/emulated/0 on modern devices.

Comment: read about [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). you simply can't/shouldn't get access to root folder. if you want to manipulate images data then there is `MediaStore` API available

Comment: You can also use `getExternalStorageDirectories(type: type)` method of the `path_provider` plugin which should work irrespective of the scoped storage thing, but hardcoding wouldn't be an option

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/79595de6752d75e226d601e275776e709e343f69/packages/path_provider/path_provider/example/lib/main.dart#L102

check for example